# Spring MVC: Dynamic Param Name or Param Name using Regex?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-bootgrid

I'm trying out this grid component called [jQuery Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/). In AJAX mode, it `POST`s parameters to the server and the one related to sorting is sent like this:

```
sort[colname]=desc
```

The `colname` part changes depending on how you sort the grid.

Is there any way in Spring MVC using `@RequestParam` to capture that `sort` param?

For example, something like:

```
@RequestParam("sort[{\\*}]") Map<String, String> sort
```

That's just a wild guess and I doubt there is any clean way to do it. Any suggestions on how to handle it would be great.

---

Update: Also tried this simpler version which I actually thought might work

```
@RequestParam("sort") Map<String, String> sort
```

Answer (score 2):

See on bootgrid forum: https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/111

It is really silly but because cannot parse dynamic parameter on server side, you need to create new request parameters from the sort parameter by defining requestHandler in your bootgrid configuration in the following way:

```
requestHandler: function (request) {
  if (request.sort) {
    request.sortBy = Object.keys(request.sort)[0]; //this only gets first sort param
    request.sortDir = request.sort[request.sortBy];
    delete request.sort
  }
  return request;
}
```

And in Spring Controller:

```
@RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false) final String sortBy,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortDir", required = false) final String sortDir
```

Do not forget to mark these parameters as not required because sort is not always posted to server side.