# How to handle RequestParam with bracket in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

How can I handle url [webix](http://docs.webix.com/samples/40_serverside/01_php_vanila/11_datatable_sort_filter.html) sorting and filter like this :

myhost.com/film?page=1&sort[title]=asc&filter[title]=cat&filter[year]=1998

in spring mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/film", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Phone> listFilm(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
        @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) String sort ) {

    int page = (page != null) ? page : 0;

    return filmService.getAll(page, sort);
}
```

is other way to get requestparams sort[title]=asc (with squarebracket in params) ?
similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361170/spring-mvc-dynamic-param-name-or-param-name-using-regex)

I try in PHP work fine to get params with bracket

```
$sortArr = array();
if (isset($_GET["sort"])){ // get param sort[title]=asc
    foreach($_GET["sort"] as $name => $dir){
        array_push($sortArr,$db->escapeString($name)." ".$dir);
    }
    if(count($sortArr))
        $str .= " ORDER BY ".implode(",",$sortArr);
}
```

Thanks any help/references I appreciate  to solve this.